# is Spring Security custom login method cancels redirec?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

So basiclly redirect to `/index.xhtml` doesn't work after login. I can't figure out how to fix it but I think what is the problem with my code, if someone could help I'd be glad.

I have `login()` method, which in my opinion lacks something:

```
public String login() {
        try {
            Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword());
            Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException) {
        //handle exception
    } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
        //handle exception
    }
    return "loggedin";
}
```

Also in my `securityContext`:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" create-session="always">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/?accessDenied=true"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/index.xhtml" always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/"/>
</sec:http>
```

Am I right that redirect doesn't work is because I have custom login method that doesn't use the `.xml` settings?
How can I fix that?

**EDIT:**

```
<h:form prependId="false">
<h:panelGroup id="loginRender" layout="block">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
        <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" value="#{loginBean.username}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="LOGIN"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" value="#{loginBean.password}"></h:inputSecret>
        <h:outputText value="PASSWORD"></h:outputText>

        <h:commandButton id="login_button" value="LOG IN" action="#{loginBean.login}"> <!-- Login button, with login() action -->
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using spring security's form login you're not supposed to handle the login yourself.
Spring's form login handler will handle the login operation for you. The login handler is pretty configurable and will most likely serve your needs.

```
<security:http>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" login-processing-url="/login"
        password-parameter="username" username-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/index.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?error"/>
</security:http>
```

The `login-page` attribute tells spring what the login page of your application is. It will redirect unauthenticated users to this page when they access a secured page. The `login-processing-url` attribute specifies the url to which the login form will POST the login credentials. The `username-parameter`and `password-parameter` attributes tell spring which parameters the contain the username and password. After a successful login spring will redirect the user to the `default-target-url` page. After a failed login attempt the user will be redirected to the `authentication-failure-url`.

It's not necessary configure all this if you're happy with the default values of these attributes. All this and more is pretty well explained in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity) so you really should take at look at it.

**UPDATE**

The login form on your `index.xhtml` page should look like this given the example form-login configuration above. The action of your form must match the value of the `login-processing-url`. Spring security will handle login request when the form is submitted.

```
<form name='loginForm' action="/login" method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='username' placeholder="username">
  <input type='text' name='password' placeholder="password">
</form>
```

Comment: So let's say I have form that I put in my post edition. It's in index.xhtml. Should I just cut the action from login button and spring would know that it's this login form? Login and password fields have default id's for spring security so that would work if I get that correctly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. I've added an example login form to make the answer more complete.